# Handling IP signed URL and changing IPs

Tags: security, url, ip

I have a webserver which only allows downloading of files when you pass along a token on the querystring. This token (basically a hash) is compared to the hash result of the filepath + remote ip.

This has worked perfectly! However since a project of mine has gained more public interest obscure issues have started to show.

People retrieve the signed urls from an API. API load balances the request and returns a valid URL for the requesting IP. However, some people have some really funky network setups and can basically change their IP address from request to request! Eg. Some university networks route all internet through a loadbalanced proxy.

This is very problematic... I have been trying to come up with an alternative but I'm kinda stuck. The only thing I can come up with is an expiring link instead which is not IP bound but that brings other kinds of issues.

What kind of options do I have other than expiring URLs? What could I do to still use the IP based system? I cannot trust proxy headers. I need to work with information the users cant directly manipulate...

I have also thought about generating a token for an IP range instead. But its not ideal and only solves the problem when the IPs are within range (of which I have already seen cases). So I'm stuck at the moment.

Would love to read about what you guys might suggest.

Comment: What is the threat you are trying to protect against?

Comment: Good question. Basically sharing of the URLs to the files. Generally once requested through the API and approved, youll immediately start downloading one or more files. This is also why expiring tokens are problematic. As there is no telling how long one might need to download stuff and I want to send out signed urls in batch. Not one by one. This killing for the bandwidth as sometimes more than a thousand files will have to be downloaded. Only those approved by the API are to access the files from the assigned loadbalanced server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is impossible I'm afraid.

You basically want to authenticate a user (the person) without.. well, authenticating the user. Anything you have in the request can be forged by the client, which means another client can make the very same request whatever you do, as long as clients cooperate and share data. The only difference that is somewhat harder to forge over TCP is the client IP, which on the other hand changes sometimes as you also noted.

So there is no cryptographic (=reasonably secure) solution.

If you want to make it somewhat harder for an attacker and your clients are browsers, you can try [fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org) the [browser](https://amiunique.org). That's suprisingly accurate in many cases, but obviously can also be forged. It does raise the bar a bit for people trying to share links though.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, not so weird I couldn't come up with a solution! I'll investigate your links and report back :)